# Call Function in BASH Script using If/Then/Else Statement

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to call a function in script by using an if/then/else statement, but I keep getting no output when I run it.  For example:

```
    start()
    {
    if [ -z /etc/redhat-release ]
       then mta
    else cron
    fi
    }

    mta()
    {
    exim -bpc
    }

    cron()
    {
    crontab -l
    }
```

Is this possible to do in BASH?

Comment: `man test`, look at the description for `-z`.

Comment: this does work @ my pc.
I copied the code to /tmp/test and than:  
 gm@mvrds:~$ . /tmp/test  
 gm@mvrds:~$ start  
 no crontab for gm

Comment: @thatbobguy Did you actually call the `start()` function?

Comment: You're right cassianoleal I forgot to call start().  Once I put that in it works as expected.  Can't believe I didn't see that before.  I guess it's hard to see the forest through the trees. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note:

1. Declare function before the function which calls it, this is always a good habit;
2. `cron` is a common command in Unix/Linux system, use another name for your function please.

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    mta()
     {
         # your code here
     }

     mycron()
     {
         # your code here
     }

     start()
     {
         if [ -z /etc/redhat-release ]; then
             mta
         else
             mycron
         fi
     }

     start
   ```

Comment: As explained in the other answer,`1.` is incorrect, and if they are not using the common command `2.` is also not needed.

Comment: Declaring functions "in order" is a perfectly reasonable habit it just doesn't matter here at all (and there are many valid reasons not to follow that habit/pattern).

Answer (score -1):

Sure, this is possible you just need to define the function, before you call it first. In this case you have to define the functions called in the start function before the start function.

Comment: Order of definition doesn't matter. Order of usage does. This order of definition is fine assuming `start` isn't called until after all three functions are defined.